# Angular 4 ngx-popover - [popoverCloseOnMouseOutside]="true" does not close the popover,when mouse taken outside the popover

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, popover

I'm using popover from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-popover .When I use [popoverCloseOnMouseOutside]="true", my popover opens on hover but does not close at all, even when hovered outside the popover or clicked outside. Here is the sample code used:

```
<popover-content #LabelPopover><div innerHTML={{PopoverContentTest}}></div></popover-content>
                <span [popover]="LabelPopover" [popoverOnHover]="true" popoverPlacement="right" [popoverCloseOnMouseOutside]="true" [popoverCloseOnClickOutside]="true">Here is the info</span>
```

PopoverContentTest is populated from component.ts file which is a HTMl string to be loaded inside the popover.[popoverCloseOnMouseOutside] being set to true but the popover does not close and remains open,there is no way to close it unless I refresh the page. Any suggestions would help.
Thanks!

Comment: what is the version you are using? latest with angular4?

Comment: Version I have is - "ngx-popover": "0.0.16", and Angular: 4.4.6

Comment: try using [popoverCloseOnMouseOutside]="true"  only

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan, I had tried that as well, din't help much.